# How to generate the same colors across two barcharts using Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, colors

I have made a horizontal barchart using a colormap like below. This chart is based off `values_1` in the DataFrame.

I would now like to make a second chart using `values_2` but I am trying to fix the colors respective to the first chart. e.g. `L` still being pink in chart 2, irrespective of sorting.

Is there a way to generate and pass a dictionary of these colours to matplotlib for the next chart like `colors = {"M":[0.121569,0.466667,0.705882,1], "L":[0.682353,0.780392,0.909804,1]}` or perhaps a better way of doing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

places = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([15,12,22,11,14,13,17,19,16,14,19,11,10,13,17],[5,2,4,9,1,1,3,7,9,3,3,1,2,3,8]),
             index=places,columns=["values_1","values_2"])

df = df.sort_values('values_1',ascending=False)


colors = [i for i in [plt.get_cmap('tab20')(range(0,len(places)))]][0]

fig, ax  = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
y_pos = np.arange(len(places))
ax.barh(y_pos,df["values_1"].sort_values(ascending=True),color=colors)
plt.yticks(y_pos,df.index)
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib horizontal barchart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an extra column that stores the order of the first sorting.  Then you can reorder the colors using that order as index:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

places = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
num_p = len(places)

df = pd.DataFrame({"values_1": [15, 12, 22, 11, 14, 13, 17, 19, 16, 14, 19, 11, 10, 13, 17],
                   "values_2": [5, 2, 4, 9, 1, 1, 3, 7, 9, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 8]},
                  index=places)
df.sort_values('values_1', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df["order1"] = np.arange(num_p)

colors = plt.get_cmap('tab20')(range(0, num_p))
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 5))

y_pos = np.arange(num_p)
ax1.barh(y_pos, df["values_1"], color=colors)
ax1.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax1.set_yticklabels(df.index)
ax1.margins(y=0.02)
ax1.set_title("values_1")

df.sort_values('values_2', ascending=True, inplace=True)
ax2.barh(y_pos, df["values_2"], color=colors[df["order1"]])
ax2.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax2.set_yticklabels(df.index)
ax2.set_title("values_2")
ax2.margins(y=0.02)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]